# Using URL fragment to determine which jquery function is run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fragment

I want to link to a page like (domain.com/page#loadThickBox1) and have it run jquery function that loads a thickbox by default. What code do I need to run to accomplish this?

For instance, these might be a few links:

domain.com/page#loadThickBox1

domain.com/page#loadThickBox2

domain.com/page#loadThickBox3

NOT like this:

domain.com/page/loadThickBox1

domain.com/page/loadThickBox2

domain.com/page/loadThickBox3

Comment: What have you tried? What was wrong with the other question (exactly the same) you asked?

Comment: I currently open the thickboxes via onclick function with a button. I want to (in addition) be able to open them by default when the page loads. I closed my last question because people thought I was trying to do stuff with pushstate, which I'm not.

Comment: 1) Check if the window location has a hash. 2) call the ThickBox on the element identified by the window location hash. 3) done.

Comment: Check out one of the many excellent route libraries such as http://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use location.hash

```
$(function() {
    switch( location.hash.replace('#','') ){
    case 'loadThickBox1':
        //do something!
        loadThickBox1();
        break;
    case 'loadThickBox2':
        //do something!
        loadThickBox2();
        break;
    case 'loadThickBox3':
        //do something!
        loadThickBox3();
        break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location.href.split('#')[1]
```

This will get you the words after the #. Load the appropriate box given this value.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the **hashchange** event, parse the hash and run your function accordingly.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8n2Lu/)

```
function handleHash(hash) {
    var hash = hash.replace('#', '');

    if (!hash) return;

    console.log('Loading thick box ' + hash.slice(-1));
}

window.addEventListener('hashchange', function () {
    handleHash(location.hash);
});

//handle initial hash when page loads
handleHash(location.hash);
```